# executing the "prepare for segue" method in a split view

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a universal application that is very basic. It is a master detail. When I segue from the master to the detail, I set the text in a label, and set the title of the destination view controller with an NSString. This works fine on iPhone, but on iPad, it doesn't set the title or the label. Here is the code I am using to set everything:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *object = dailyGramsNumbers[indexPath.row];
        NSString *object1 = dailyGramsBody [indexPath.row];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setDetailItem:object1];
        [[segue destinationViewController] setTitle:object];

    }
}
```

thanks for any help!

here is the code I am using now (in addition to the above code):

```
- (void)tableView:

    (UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            NSString *object = dailyGramsNumbers[indexPath.row];
            [self.splitViewController.viewControllers[1] setTitle:object];

            self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using a SplitViewController? In that case I guess, that on an iPad no Segue is executed, because both parts (master and detail) are shown together. I'm just guessing, but maybe that helps

Comment: yeah that is what I figured. but I am just trying to figure out how I would execute that code on the split view in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A split view controller has a viewControllers property, and the controller at index 1 will be the detail controller. So, you can accomplish the same task on the iPad version by putting in this code,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *object = dailyGramsNumbers[indexPath.row];
    NSString *object1 = dailyGramsBody[indexPath.row];
    [self.splitViewController.viewControllers[1] setDetailItem:object1];
    [self.splitViewController.viewControllers[1] setTitle:object];
}
```

You should import the DetailController.h file into the .m file of the master controller, and you might have to cast self.splitViewController.viewcontrollers[1] to your detail controller class.

After Edit:

If the detail controller is embedded in a navigation controller, code like this should work,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *object = dailyGramsNumbers[indexPath.row];
    NSString *object1 = dailyGramsBody[indexPath.row];
    [(DetailViewController *)[self.splitViewController.viewControllers[1] topViewController] setDetailItem:object1];
    [(DetailViewController *)[self.splitViewController.viewControllers[1] topViewController] setTitle:object];
}
```

Comment: This is the code I have in the RPMasterViewController.m (in addition to the code that I originally posted.- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        NSString *object = dailyGramsNumbers[indexPath.row];
        [self.splitViewController.viewControllers[1] setTitle:object];
        
        self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
    }
}
 The label works now and is being set, but the title is not.

Comment: @user2991787, is your detail controller in a navigation controller?

Comment: Hmmm... then I don't understand why the code I posted to set the detail item would have worked. Did you change that code at all? self.splitViewController.viewControllers[1] should be the navigation controller, so it wouldn't have a setDetailItem method. I've updated my code to show what worked for me, when the detail controller is embedded in a navigation controller.

Comment: If you want to know exactly how everything looks in the storyboard of my application, just create a new master detail project in Xcode. I have not changed anything in the storyboard and am using some of the code that came with it

Comment: just checked and the code you posted to set the detail item didn't work, this code did: self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;